# Hiding pregnancy during the first 3 months

Tags: minhag, pregnancy-birth, ayin-hara-evil-eye

There is a tradition - or whatever you may call it - not to tell people about your pregnancy early on.

First off, is there a Torah basis to it? Or just common sense? (if things go wrong people will still say Mazal Tov...)

Secondly, when someone asks "are you pregnant?" or "is your wife pregnant?", is OK to lie and say NO??

Comment: The gemara ([*Nidda* 8b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=8b&format=text) and elsewhere) mentions that a woman's pregnancy is not visible to others until three months have elapsed: וכמה הכרת העובר? סומכוס אומר משום רבי מאיר: שלשה חדשים, ואע"פ שאין ראיה לדבר זכר לדבר, שנאמר ויהי כמשלש חדשים.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an [excerpt from Kovetz Minhagim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15680&pgnum=10), An Anthology of Chabad Lubavitch customs regarding
pregnancy,
childbirth,
circumcision,
redemption of the firstborn,
and the birth of girl:

> It is the custom of chassidim who are careful to
>   conduct their lifestyles according to the practices of old that
>   they conceal their wives' pregnancies until they have entered
>   the fifth month. Undoubtedly, this practice has an inner
>   foundation. Of course, the precaution is about publicizing
>   the pregnancy.
>   It does not apply to divulging it to very close
>   relatives without broadcasting it.

See there for sources in the footnote. Of interest is footnote 3, which quotes a letter of the Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe:

> "The accepted
>   practice is that until three months of pregnancy it is concealed even
>   from very close relatives..."

Comment: [see above](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31389/hiding-pregnancy-during-the-first-3-months#comment80705_31389).  This is certainly neither uniquely Chabad nor uniquely Jewish.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman: The question is asking for a jewish source, which I offered

Comment: @Menachem No, it's asking for a Torah basis.

Comment: @DoubleAA: do you feel my answer doesn't qualify?

Comment: Not really. What is the basis?

Comment: While not a Torah basis - it is still good to know that renown rabbis recommend it.

Comment: What would you say about the second part of the question - the "lying"?

Answer (score 2):

As a partial answer, concerning the lying part, it may be adduced that it is permitted to lie from Rema ([resp. §2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1204&st=&pgnum=5&hilite=)) who permitted a woman to have contact with her husband despite her telling inquirers, early on in her pregnancy, in order to be shielded from the evil eye that she wore clothing designated for her menstruation period because she was unclean and indeed said she was unclean. He does not mention the (non)issue of her lying. This ruling was also brought by Shach (YD 185:5) and likewise did not raise the issue of lying.

[R. Shimon Hirari](http://m.bhol.co.il/article.aspx?id=80941) (resp. Lev Simchah, EH §12) justified a woman's white lie, which she told people that she had a *ruach* (I can't determine if *she* meant a spirit or bloated), by demonstrating that pregnancy can be referred to as *ruach*.

However, in both cases it should be noted the woman did not explicitly lie by saying she is not pregnant but rather gave "alternative facts".

Answer (score 1):

This custom is [much](http://www.netplaces.com/pregnancy/month-three/spreading-the-word.htm) [wider](http://pregnancy.about.com/od/newlypregnant/a/whenannounce.htm) than the Jewish world.

[Most women](http://pregnant.thebump.com/pregnancy/first-trimester/qa/when-to-tell-people-im-pregnant.aspx) do not widely publicize their pregnancies until the third month because [the rate of, G-d-forbid, miscarriage drops significantly at week 12](http://www.easybabylife.com/miscarriage-statistics-by-week.html). By month 5, women start to show, so it becomes nearly impossible to keep it a secret.

However, my wife would ream me out my if I ever lied as a response to that question. (She would say that I should have changed the conversation topic.) She'd say that saying "no" is basically telling the *ayin hara* you don't want it.

Comment: I didn't realize the *ayin hara* was an independent entity. Am I wrong, or did you perhaps mean *sitra achra* or some such?

Comment: @Fred I'm quoting my wife who likes to speak in Yiddish superstition.  She also might say "telling G-d you don't want it".